# how to reduce compile time: in case of including an untouched header file

Tags: c++, include, shared-libraries, external

I have a function defined in `file1.h` as below:

```
/** file1.h **/
def testFunc(){}
```

file1.h is written once and will not be modified during the development. But I have to use `testFunc()` in my code say in `file2`.

```
/** file2.h **/
#include "file1.h"
testFunc(); //some sort of use
```

The problem is every time I make a change to `file2.h`, the compiler obviously also compiles `file1.h`, which takes time. Any suggestion on how to stop the compiler from compiling the file every time?

Comment: Precompiled headers?

Comment: Your functions should be declared in header files and defined in c++ files. That way the .o files compiled from the c++ files do not have to be regenerated as long as the c++ and h file don't change.

Comment: @PeteBlackerThe3rd it's an external file

Comment: @Ayxan I am aware of that for VS. Can you suggest a ref how to do it in linux?

Comment: As a side note: there are often redundant includes in big projects. One may want to reduce that redundancy, for by using `include-what-you-use` tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use precompiled headers as a solution. How you do that depends on your Compiler and environment. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) is a start for GCC:

> To create a precompiled header file, simply compile it as you would
>   any other file, if necessary using the -x option to make the driver
>   treat it as a C or C++ header file. You may want to use a tool like
>   `make` to keep the precompiled header up-to-date when the headers it
>   contains change.
>
> A precompiled header file is searched for when `#include` is seen in the
>   compilation. As it searches for the included file (see [Search Path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path) in
>   The C Preprocessor) the compiler looks for a precompiled header in
>   each directory just before it looks for the include file in that
>   directory. The name searched for is the name specified in the `#include`
>   with ‘.gch’ appended. If the precompiled header file cannot be used,
>   it is ignored.

Comment: would creating a shared library also help?

Comment: @JalilNourisa It probably would, I might be wrong though